# Inserting data using a Web Service - cURL & PHP

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm trying to build a webpage which will connect to a web service and add data to the database.

Being new to cURL and Web Services what I thought I could do since I want to have a form in my html is have that form connected to a php script which contains my cURL and then have the cURL connect to the web service to update the data. Stil not sure if that is the logic behind web services.

The issue is that despise getting a http code of 200 OK no data is inserted to the database.

index form:

```
<form method="post" action="addPoiCurl.php">
    <input type="text" name="addPoiName" placeholder="Name" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="addPoiCountry" placeholder="Country" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="addPoiRegion" placeholder="region" />
    <br />
    Choose the type of POI<br />
    <select name="addPoiType"> 
        <option value="empty">...</option>
        <option value="city">City</option>
        <option value="hill">Hill</option>
        <option value="industrial estate">Industrial Estate</option>
        <option value="lost city">Lost City</option>
        <option value="moor">Moor</option>
        <option value="mountian">Mountain</option>
        <option value="point">Point</option>
        <option value="port">Port</option>
        <option value="pub">Pub</option>
        <option value="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
        <option value="town">Town</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="addPoiDescription" placeholder="Description" 
style="width:200px; height:100px" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
```

cURL PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$aPoiName = $_POST["addPoiName"];
$aPoiCountry = $_POST["addPoiCountry"];
$aPoiRegion = $_POST["addPoiRegion"];
$aPoiType = $_POST["addPoiType"];
$aPoiDescription = $_POST["addPoiDescription"];


// Curl -----------------
// Initialize
$connection = curl_init();

//URL to sned the request to
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://addPoiWebService.php');

$dataToPost=
[   "Name" => $aPoiName ,
    "Country" => $aPoiCountry ,
    "Region" => $aPoiRegion , 
    "Type" => $aPoiType ,
    "Description" => $aPoiDescription
];
//Execute the request 
curl_setopt($connection,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($connection,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$dataToPost);
$response = curl_exec($connection);

//HTTP CODE
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($connection, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "The script returned the HTTP status code: $httpCode <br />";
//close 
curl_close($connection);

?>
```

(keep in mind that I changed the link in the connection just for this post)

as for the web service php:

```
$aPoiName = $_POST["Name"];
$aPoiCountry = $_POST["Country"];
$aPoiRegion = $_POST["Region"];
$aPoiType = $_POST["Type"];
$aPoiDescription = $_POST["Description"];


if($aPoiName !="" && $aPoiCountry !="" && $aPoiRegion !="" && $aPoiType 
!="empty" && $aPoiDescription !=""){

header("Content-type: application/json");

$results = $conn->query("INSERT INTO pointsofinterest (name, country, 
region, type, description) VALUES ('$aPoiName', '$aPoiCountry', 
'$aPoiRegion', '$aPoiType', '$aPoiDescription')");

}
else{
echo "Missing Information";
}
```

(the connection to the database was deleted as well on purpose for this post)

The results I get is just the echo of 200 from the http code check. 
No data is inserted to the database.

Comment: You'll need to do some error checking. Check for errors after your query (Information for[mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and  [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). You're not returning anything in your if block, so add some data there as well. You're also open for SQL injection and quote confusion. To prevent that, look into parameter binding and prepared statements: [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I'm aware that my code isn't secure, this is for study and practice purposes not for a real life use but thank you!
As for the IF statement I don't see how adding a return message in my Web Service.php will help. After pressing Submit in my form the only thing I get back is the http code response on the addPoicURL.php

Comment: The response is more for information purposes. And while you may not be worried about security, not having to worry about quoting issues (like O'Leary) helps a lot. Definitely check for the errors to see if there's any information being returned from MySQL.

Comment: Will do thanks. Could you just tell me if my logic is right? Am I supposed to link my form to a php file containing the cURL and then have it connect to the web service?

Comment: problem fixed! YEAAHY!! It was a problem with the if statement on my php